# ReadFile not reading the bytes correctly

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to read a file using readfile, store it into a wide array, then write it into another file. Problem is, when I put them side by side in HxD some bytes are correct (the text, for example) but everything else is completely different. I can't run it either

```
struct a
{
    BYTE* buff;
    long siz;
};

int main()
{
    HANDLE hFile;
    a struct_a;

    if (hFile = CreateFileW(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, nullptr))
    {
        long lFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, nullptr);

        if (lFileSize)
        {
            struct_a.siz = lFileSize;
            struct_a.buff = new BYTE[struct_a.siz];

            if (ReadFile(hFile, struct_a.buff, struct_a.siz,
                nullptr, nullptr))
            {
                CloseHandle(hFile);
            }

        }
    }

    HANDLE h = CreateFileA("C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\notepad_new.exe", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nullptr,
        CREATE_NEW, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);

    WriteFile(h, struct_a.buff, struct_a.siz, nullptr, nullptr);

return 0;
}
```

I want it to be able to read the file correctly and then write it and have me be able to run it.

---

As a bonus, I also tried writing some bytes around the end of the file after I read it by doing

```
struct_a.buff[struct_a.siz - 5] = L'A';
```

but it never did show up anywhere. But when I tried writing it at the beginning (removing the brackets) it wrote it fine.

EDIT: I tried reading it afterwards and it read the correct letter weirdly enough

***EDIT 2:*** Picture of issue:
[image]

Comment: Sounds a lot like you don't want to work on the file as a text file and should treat it as binary data instead.

Comment: Explain further mate

Comment: Can you guys tell me what my issues are instead of downvoting me? I'm not an expert, but I tried my best to make everything myself so I figured some errors could arise

Comment: Haven't voted yet.  But it's likely voters are discouraged by your code example lacking information.  This might not be a true representation of your actual program.  Notably, we do not see whether these reads and writes occur in the same function, or exactly where `struct_a` is defined.  Regarding your "bonus" test, that raises alarm bells.  If you do not see any change, then it's possible you never actually write (perhaps file is already open?) -- check the handle is valid after opening the file and issue an error if not.  Regarding binary mode, that's necessary to avoid newline translation.

Comment: Actually the issue with the "bonus" is that you have allocated a `wchar_t` array.  Do _not_ read your file as `wchar_t` values!!  The file size is in _bytes_.  When you are addressing `size-5` element in a `wchar_t` array, that is way off the end of the file.

Comment: is it because wchar_t is 2 bytes? that could be it. Also, I have changed my question. I'll try reading it as a byte right now

Comment: Simple approach: don't bother with wide characters. Just read a blob of bytes  into a buffer and write the buffer to the other file. The bytes will take care of themselves. If some of the bytes happen to be wide characters, bytes are agnostic. They don't care. Whatever uses the file has to care.

Comment: Hah. By the time I got back to the finish the comment, the point was pretty much moot.

Comment: I have changed it into BYTE, and while perhaps that will fix the issues with writing values, the notepad.exe file is still not read/written correctly @user4581301 no worries bro I appreciate anyone trying to help with my issue,im sure theres some simple error happening that i cant catch

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/avdWp3g

Comment: No one has answered the question and I don't mind if my comments are made invalid, so  far as I'm concerned feel free to update the question with your new code.

Comment: A warning about posting links to images: They are chum for downvote sharks. There's a whole bunch of reasons you shouldn't use them as a primary source of information. This is more of a secondary source, so go nuts. Just be careful with how you use them.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind bro, just wanted to expand on what I mean by "it's copying the wrong bytes, but the strings are intact"

Comment: I don't recall seeing the behavior you are showing. However I have not worked with these APIs directly in over a decade.

Comment: Is your program a 32-bit program running on a 64-bit system?

Comment: Also, is HxD a 32-bit program running on a 64-bit system?

Comment: ... Because if it is, [file system redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/file-system-redirector) will mean that you may not be reading the file you think you're reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The left file in the screenshot is a 32-bit EXE file. The byte you have highlighted that is different is the address of the [IMAGE_NT_HEADERS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_image_nt_headers) structure in the file.

At address 0xFC, 4 bytes into this structure, the 2 bytes are 4C 01. This is the Machine field in [IMAGE_FILE_HEADERS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_image_file_header) and this value indicates the machine is "i386" (i.e. a 32-bit program).

In the right file, the address is 0xEC instead, and the bytes are 64 86, which is "AMD64" (i.e. this is a 64-bit program).

Probably your program is a 32-bit program, and so it accesses the 32-bit version of System32, because of a Windows feature called [file system redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/file-system-redirector) (thanks to Paul Sanders for the link). On 64-bit Windows, 32-bit programs have System32 redirected to a different folder (which is really called SysWOW64) - according to this table:

```
                   32-bit System32        64-bit System32

32-bit program   C:\Windows\System32    C:\Windows\sysnative
64-bit program   C:\Windows\SysWOW64    C:\Windows\System32
```

You can solve this problem by either reading the notepad.exe from sysnative, or comparing it against the one in SysWOW64 instead of the one in System32, or by compiling your program as 64-bit.

Comment: You are very much right, I can't believe I did not see this. I even had a ReadProcessMemory call return mismatched length because I was trying to access a x64 process from a x86 compiled exe. Thanks a lot